# ExpandableListView cant automatically scroll

Tags: android, scroll, xamarin.android, expandablelistview

I've been struggling with this problem ridiculos amount of time now. I got 5 expandable listviews which contains info for every day of the week, and i can swipe between them. Everything works just fine, except that when i start the activity i want the current list view to be automatically scrolled down (not by user) to the current day. And..NOTHING happens to it.

SSCCE:

```
public void Test()
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < this.numberOfWeeks; i++)
                {
                     // Relative layout to represent the current visible area
                     RelativeLayout screen = new RelativeLayout(this);

                     //LayoutParameters for the screen, fills the whole screen
                     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams newParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FillParent, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FillParent);
                     screen.Id = 1000;
                     screen.LayoutParameters = newParams;


                     //An ExpandableListView is created with some parameters not important for this example
                     ExpandableListView newEListView = this.CreateExpandableListView( //..params..// )

                     screen.AddView(newEListView);

                     // Set this newEListView to the array of expandablelistviews
                     this.expandableListViews[i] = newEListView;
                }

                // Some more stuff is done, and finally when data is loaded and everything shows up just fine..
                // Lets make it automatically scroll down to the current day!

                // This does nothing
                this.expandableListViews[3].SetSelection(4); // 4 is current day

                // Same here
                this.expandableListViews[3].SetSelectionFromTop(4, 200);

            }
```

Might be worth mentioning that manual scrolling works just fine..

Answer (score 0):

SetSelection does not work in this way, an alternate to what you might be trying is

```
mexpandableList.smoothScrollToPosition(groupPosition);
```

and if you want, set the background color of the selected row so it looks highlighted.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no such method in Monodroid..:(

Comment: http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aAndroid.Widget.AbsListView.SmoothScrollToPosition%28System.Int32%29

Answer (score 0):

Try the `setSelectedGroup` method.